# Is Null in Windows equal to zero?

Tags: ida, disassembly, malware

(This question refers to assembly language.)  I'm a little bit confused.  I've encountered many times Windows functions that are supposed to return a Handle, and if they don't they return NULL.  Why do the checks afterward check against zero?  Zero isn't equal to NULL.

As an example:
GetModuleHandleA:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea

[image]

Comment: Side note: I think originally all those methods were documented with returning zero on failure but now most switched to "NULL", but you can still find "zero" - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexa (which is just Ex version of function in the question)

Answer (score 13):

In C, and many other low-level programming languages the term `NULL` is equivalent to `0`.

The C standard requires NULL to be `#define`d to an "implementation defined value", however all implementations have chosen (for obvious reasons) to use `0` for that purpose. For that reason if you'll attempt to "See definition" for `NULL`, many IDEs will drop you in a line `#define NULL 0` or something similar.

This has the additional benefit of `NULL` evaluating to `false` making conditional statements readable and intuitive.

The proper way, from a strict standard following perspective, would be to use `NULL` and not 0, and that's what most developers do. The compiler (or pre-processor in the case of `#define NULL 0`) will however translate that to a `0`.

Some higher level languages (such as javascript and C++) use special expressions to signify null. One example is C++'s `nullptr`, that since C++11 is the required definition of `NULL`. Javascript uses a special object, `null`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117015/discussion-on-answer-by-nirizr-does-null-in-windows-equal-to-zero).

Answer (score 6):

When looking at Windows API calls or disassembly of C/C++ code, NULL Is always 0, in Visual Studio this is defined in vcruntime.h

```
#ifndef NULL
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define NULL 0
    #else
        #define NULL ((void *)0)
    #endif
#endif
```

However if you are looking at higher level languages NULL will not necessarily be zero, for example within .NET C# code like this:

```
if (args == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("null!");
}
```

Will compile to Common Intermediate Language (CIL). You can see with **ldnull** null is not simply zero.

```
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldnull
IL_0003: ceq
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: brfalse.s IL_0016
IL_000a: ldstr "null!"
IL_000f: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Comment: `0` in a pointer context has special meaning in C and C++.  This definition does *not* definitively tell you that the object-representation for a null pointer is `0x00000000`.  (That is the case in all mainstream C++ implementations for x86, and almost all mainstream C and C++ implementations ever.  There are a few historical exceptions: [When was the NULL macro not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597156) mentions some and quotes the C standard re: `0` in the source vs. the bit-pattern used.)

Comment: This means ISO C++ doesn't guarantee that `memset(ptr_array, 0, 16)` would initialize pointers to NULL, or in the OP's case that a compare would check against zero in the generated asm.

Answer (score 6):

ISO C and C++ *allow* implementations to use a non-zero bit-pattern as the object representation for a null pointer, despite [requiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c) that a literal `0` or `(void*)0` in the source (in a pointer context) is evaluated as a null pointer, equivalent to `NULL`.  **Reasoning based on source definitions like `#define NULL 0` is *not* sufficient in C or C++.**

**But fortunately for everyone's sanity, all modern C and C++ implementations for x86 (and other modern ISAs) *do* use `0` in asm as the bit-pattern for NULL.**  This makes non-portable code like `memset(ptr_array, 0, size)` work as expected, equivalent to a loop that sets each element to `NULL`.

[When was the NULL macro not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0) is asking about source-level non-zero definitions, but I think that's not allowed in modern C.  The answers mention several historical machines that had non-zero null pointer bit-patterns.  (i.e. what you'd see in the asm for code like `do {...} while(p = p->next);`)

---

**Remember that in asm, pointers are just 64-bit (or 32-bit) integers**.  The whole idea of `NULL` is in-band signalling, not some special thing that isn't even a pointer-sized integer.  So we have to pick some constant.

`0` is a convenient sentinel value because many ISAs can branch slightly more efficiently on a value being non-zero than checking for any other value.  e.g. ARM has `cbnz` to branch on non-zero without needing a `cmp`.  x86 has a minor code-size optimization of `test eax, eax` / `jnz` instead of `cmp eax, 0` / `jnz`.  ([Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806)).  If FLAGS are already set by another arithmetic instruction, no `test` would be needed, but that's unusual for null pointer tests: usually you don't do math on a pointer and *then* for NULL.

(You're not seeing that optimization in your asm because your debug build stores to memory before testing.)

Also, `0` is easy to generate.  Some large number might take a larger instruction, or most instructions, to create in a register.  (e.g. x86 [`xor eax,eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) instead of `mov eax, imm32`).  And zero-initialized static storage like `static int *table = NULL;` can be in the BSS instead of `.data` - modern systems zero-init the BSS.

---

On some systems (especially embedded) the `0` address isn't special, and you actually have system-management stuff there, like the start of a table of interrupt handlers.  So `0` can be a valid address, as well as being equal to `NULL`.  This kinda sucks, so this is where one might actually want a non-zero object representation for null pointers.  @Simon Richter [comments](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/does-null-in-windows-equal-to-zero/26442#comment40961_26435) about hacking an ARM compiler to use `0x20000000` as the NULL bit-pattern.

On systems using virtual memory (like Windows), we can simply avoid ever mapping the page containing that address, which helps detect bugs by making sure NULL-dereference actually faults.  (Remember that undefined behaviour in C and C++ is *not* required to fault, but it's certainly convenient if it does.)